# .htaccess rewrite rule causes an error 404 when multiple variables are passed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

When I use the .htaccess rewrite rule to rewrite */posts/post.php?postid=1* to */posts/1* the rewrite works and the post.php page loads.

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /posts/
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ post.php?postid=$1
</IfModule>
```

However, when I want to pass multiple variables in the URL (*/posts/post.php?date=2014-07-28&title=title%20of%20post* to */posts/2014-07-28/title%20of%20post*) an error 404 is triggered.

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /posts/
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ post.php?date=$1&title=$2
</IfModule>
```

Any help with this problem would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Read up on the QSA flag.  This is what you are looking for.

Comment: @TerryE I've read into the QSA flag, implemented the necessary changes and played around with it, however it doesn't seemed to have worked and it still causes and error 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't cover stuff like `%20` or spaces, try making it accept everything:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /posts/
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.+)$ post.php?date=$1&title=$2
</IfModule>
```

You *may* need to play around with the `NE` and/or `B` flag depending on what kind of encoded stuff you have in your URL:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /posts/
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.+)$ post.php?date=$1&title=$2 [L,NE,B,QSA]
</IfModule>
```